# reddit : onclick window.location

Tags: onclick, wordpress, reddit

I am using **reddit** sharing button in my blog but when the share button is clicked it opens in same windows rather then in new window.

What needs to be changed to make the reddit to open in new window.

I searched the similar Question and Answer in stackoverflow but they seems do not match the question which i have.

Below is the code

```
<a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false">

<img src="http://www.reddit.com/static/spreddit8.gif" 
alt="submit to reddit" border="0" /> </a>
```

Comment: I am trying with window.open and below is the code. Now its opening in new window but the current browser window also opens in reddit website to share the post.                                          <a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.open('http://www.reddit.com/submit');"> <img src="http://www.reddit.com/static/spreddit8.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0" /> </a>